# Make ShareThis (a script) load on certain pages only

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

We have a WordPress site where we use a programme to create share buttons for our site. This is called ShareThis. All we have to do to integrate it to our site is to add the following script to our header.php.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=58ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03357&product=inline-share-buttons' async='async'></script>
```

We did - and it is working perfectly. But is there a way to make this script load on our blog only, and not on every page of our site? It is slowing down our site by approximately 400 ms and is only used in our blog posts.

Comment: Would it not be cached after the first request, and then *not* take an extra 400ms on subsequent requests?

Comment: It definitely gets faster after the cache, but is there any reason to have it load on any unnecessary pages? With other words, are there any downsides to using the below suggested code to only load it on the blog? We have NO other areas where we need to use sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is an easy way to do this.
In your header, you can do this. First I will explain what, and then how you do.

You can do this easily by checking if the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable starts with 'blog' or the desired page prefix to load on, for example `http://yoursite.com/blog/(post)`

How-to:

```
if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog')) {
    // Load script
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5‌​8ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03‌​357&product=inline-s‌​hare-buttons' async='async'></script>";
}
```

Comment: Incredible. I have detected that all my blog posts start with blog. Now all I need to know is where do I add the code you added in conjuction with the old? I am assuming it all goes under the header.php, but how do I make sure that the code you added only applies to the ShareThis code and not all my other javascript?

It goes:

<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=58ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03357&product=inline-share-buttons' async='async'></script>

if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog')) {
    // Load script
}

Comment: To load the script, simply echo the script tag inside the `if` statement

 if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog')) { echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5‌​8ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03‌​357&product=inline-s‌​hare-buttons' async='async'></script>"; }

P.S. I edited my original answer

Comment: Hello. Very professional. I added:

if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog')) {
        // Load script
        echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5‌​8ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03‌​357&product=inline-s‌​hare-buttons' async='async'></script>";
    }

In my header.php, however it is not working. On the top of my page whenever I open the site it shows the code: if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog')) { // Load script echo ""; }

Comment: Ah, simple issue. Make sure to wrap the code in php tags as follows: `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: Ty! So:

<?php

if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog')) {
    // Load script
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5‌​8ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03‌​357&product=inline-s‌​hare-buttons' async='async'></script>";
}

?>

Comment: I have added the code:

<?php
if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog')) {
    // Load script
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5‌​8ff3bc2a9dabe0012b03‌​357&product=inline-s‌​hare-buttons' async='async'></script>";
}
?>

Now. This moves the error, but now the sharethis icons are gone on the /blog page.

Comment: Shoot. Maybe check the js console on chrome and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: Your code was perfect, I just messed it up. Works fine now. Added you as answer ty!